# Debian package:user and group

Tags: cmake, debian, cpack

Recently,I use cmake/cpack to make a debian package.I make succeed.But I install it on the computer(sudo dpkg -i mypcakge.deb), I find a problem: the install program's user and group is root:root.Due to some reason, my problem should run in a specific user/group. I don't know how to do this, could you help me?

Also, I don't want to modify the user and group with chown(..) after I installed the package.Is there a way to add something in the CMakeLists to do this?

Comment: I don't think many Debian packagers are familiar with Cmake for creating Debian packages. Could you post a link to some background resource, or perhaps just a snippet which shows how you are doing it?

Answer (score 0):

It is not related only to CMake, but in general when using debhelper and/or non-standard usernames.

`dh(1)` often used in `debian/rules` by default will call `dh_fixperms(1)`, which will reset owners and permissions by default.

There are basically three ways to retain owners/permissions you want:

1. if you use some **standard Debian system user/group**, you may skip
   or override `dh_fixperms(1)` and you may specify files to override owner/group for. Be sure that your package pre-depends on correct version of `base-passwd` package which contains wanted users/groups.

   You could override in your `debian/rules` like [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/695314/195954) (see `dh_fixperms(1)` man page):

   ```
   override_dh_fixperms:
       dh_fixperms --exclude matchname
   ```

   [Debian docs](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-files.html#permissions-and-owners) have more info.
2. if you create your own users and you want files/dirs to be owned by them, you will need to use `postinst` script. In it, you first need to [create users/groups if they don't already exist](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/47880/64590), and then do something like

   ```
   chown myuser:mygroup /var/log/mydir
   chmod 0750 /var/log/mydir
   ```
3. Alternatively, you can use (also in your [postinst and postrm](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-maintainerscripts.html) scripts) [dpkg-statoverride(8)](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-files.html#the-use-of-dpkg-statoverride) to change owners,groups and permissions of your (or other) files like this:

   ```
   for i in /usr/bin/foo /usr/sbin/bar; do
       # only do something when no setting exists
       if ! dpkg-statoverride --list $i >/dev/null 2>&1; then
           #include: debconf processing, question about foo and bar
           if [ "$RET" = "true" ] ; then
               dpkg-statoverride --update --add sysuser root 4755 $i
           fi
       fi
   done
   ```

   You should also handle removal, like this:

   ```
   for i in /usr/bin/foo /usr/sbin/bar; do
       if dpkg-statoverride --list $i >/dev/null 2>&1; then
           dpkg-statoverride --remove $i
       fi
   done
   ```